# User List creates duplicates?

Tags: php, html

I've made this code using a tutorial that allows me to upload users to the database. The whole thing works great, but the only problem is that it starts to show 2 of the same user over and over, the list starts expanding 5 every user i add... What could be the problem causing this?

Item in index that lays out the whole list:

```html
<h2>Names:</h2>
 <table border='1'>
  <tr>
   <th>ID</th>
   <th>Username</th>
  </tr>
  
  <?php
   $sql_list = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY username ASC";
   $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql_list) or die(mysql_error());
   $names = "";
      
   if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
     $id = $row['id'];
     $user = $row['username'];
     
     $names .= "<tr><td>$user</td></tr>";
     echo $names;
    }
   } else {
    echo "No Users Found";
   }
  ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Do either of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Either `output` the one record per iteration; or build the whole HTML block, then output the block. I think the simplest would be:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $user = $row['username'];
    echo "<tr><td>$user</td></tr>";
    }
```

... alternative approach

```
<h2>Names:</h2>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
            $sql_list = "SELECT * FROM names ORDER BY username ASC";
            $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql_list) or die(mysqli_error($db));
            $names = "";

            if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $user = $row['username'];

                    $names .= "<tr><td>$user</td></tr>";
                }
            } else {
                $names = "No Users Found";
            }
            echo $names;
        ?>
    </table>
```

Also you can't use `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*`. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Simplest example of the issue: https://eval.in/627250